# Extract and combine columns with the same name from a list of dataframes

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I got a list of 17 dataframes that contain multiple macroeconomic variables for several countries, and the dataframes' structure is like:

```r
df$CPI
 Date       US    Argentina  Vietnam  India  Indonesia  Philippines 
1564531200  1.8      54.4     2.4      3.1       3.3        2.4      
1561852800  1.6      55.8     2.2      3.2       3.3        2.7
1559260800  1.8      57.3     2.9      3.0       3.3        3.2


df$CapitalAccount
 Date          US    Argentina  Brazil  China  Turkey   Thai 
2019-06-30     0        13.8     49.0   -58.5   -7.2    27.9
2019-03-31     0        32.2     98.1   -26.3   21.4    0.0 
2018-12-31    2721      16.2     59.8   -213.1  0.5     0.0 
2018-06-30    -5        10.9     82.0   -50.6   -2.7    0.0
```

I'm trying to re-organize those dataframes by country names, like:

```r
US
Date         CPI   CapitalAccount .......(the other 14 macro variables)
2019-06-30  
2019-03-31
2018-12-31

Argentina
Date         CPI   CapitalAccount .......(the other 14 macro variables)
2019-06-30  
2019-03-31
2018-12-31
.
.
.
.
```

I've tried using a for loop to go through each dataframe in the list of dataframes and grab the column by colnames() of that dataframe, but it's not working and the result gives me many duplicate NAs and Dates.

```r
For US:

for (i in 1:length(df)){
  NewUS <- df[[i]][,which(colnames(df[[i]])=='US')]
  US <- merge(US, NewUS)
  i <- i+1
  }
US


For Argentina:
for (i in 1:length(df)){
  NewArgentina <- df[[i]][,which(colnames(df[[i]])=='Argentina')]
  Argentina <- merge(Argentina, NewArgentina)
  i <- i+1
  }
Argentina
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider base R with `reshape`, chain `merge`, and `split` for transformed named list of data frames. Helper  functions include higher-order `Map` and `Reduce`.

```
proc_reshape <- function(df, nm) {

    within(data.frame(reshape(df, varying = names(df)[-1], times = names(df)[-1],
                              v.names = nm, timevar = "Country", direction = "long"),
                      row.names = NULL), {
           Date <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(Date, origin = "1970-01-01"))
           rm(id)
    })

}

# ELEMENTWISE LOOP THROUGH DFs AND THEIR NAMES
long_list <- Map(proc_reshape, my_list, names(my_list))

# CHAIN MERGE (FULL JOIN FOR MISMATCHED DATES BY COUNTRY)
merged_df <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = c("Country", "Date"), all = TRUE), 
                    long_list)

# CREATE NEW NAMED LIST OF DFs
new_list <- split(merged_df, merged_df$Country)
```

**Output**

```
new_list  

$Argentina 
   Country         Date  CPI CapitalAccount 
1  Argentina 2018-06-29   NA           10.9 
2  Argentina 2018-12-30   NA           16.2 
3  Argentina 2019-03-30   NA           32.2 
4  Argentina 2019-05-31 57.3             NA 
5  Argentina 2019-06-29   NA           13.8 
6  Argentina 2019-06-30 55.8             NA 
7  Argentina 2019-07-31 54.4             NA 

$Brazil 
    Country      Date CPI CapitalAccount 
8   Brazil 2018-06-29  NA           82.0 
9   Brazil 2018-12-30  NA           59.8 
10  Brazil 2019-03-30  NA           98.1 
11  Brazil 2019-06-29  NA           49.0 

$China 
    Country       Date CPI CapitalAccount 
12  China   2018-06-29  NA          -50.6 
13  China   2018-12-30  NA         -213.1 
14  China   2019-03-30  NA          -26.3 
15  China   2019-06-29  NA          -58.5 

$India 
    Country       Date CPI CapitalAccount 
16  India   2019-05-31 3.0             NA 
17  India   2019-06-30 3.2             NA 
18  India   2019-07-31 3.1             NA 

$Indonesia 
   Country         Date CPI CapitalAccount 
19 Indonesia 2019-05-31 3.3             NA 
20 Indonesia 2019-06-30 3.3             NA 
21 Indonesia 2019-07-31 3.3             NA 

$Philippines 
   Country           Date CPI CapitalAccount 
22 Philippines 2019-05-31 3.2             NA 
23 Philippines 2019-06-30 2.7             NA 
24 Philippines 2019-07-31 2.4             NA 

$Thai 
   Country       Date CPI CapitalAccount 
25 Thai    2018-06-29  NA            0.0 
26 Thai    2018-12-30  NA            0.0 
27 Thai    2019-03-30  NA            0.0 
28 Thai    2019-06-29  NA           27.9 

$Turkey 
   Country       Date CPI CapitalAccount 
29  Turkey 2018-06-29  NA           -2.7 
30  Turkey 2018-12-30  NA            0.5 
31  Turkey 2019-03-30  NA           21.4 
32  Turkey 2019-06-29  NA           -7.2 

$US 
    Country       Date CPI CapitalAccount 
33       US 2018-06-29  NA             -5 
34       US 2018-12-30  NA           2721 
35       US 2019-03-30  NA              0 
36       US 2019-05-31 1.8             NA 
37       US 2019-06-29  NA              0 
38       US 2019-06-30 1.6             NA 
39       US 2019-07-31 1.8             NA 

$Vietnam 
   Country       Date CPI CapitalAccount 
40 Vietnam 2019-05-31 2.9             NA 
41 Vietnam 2019-06-30 2.2             NA 
42 Vietnam 2019-07-31 2.4             NA
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/SESM88931)</kbd>

Comment: Appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: per @Gregor's suggestion. I use `idcol` and `fill = T` to replace the for loop.
Hope this helps. In the code below, `df1` and `df2` are dummy data tables. In your case, they will be CPI, CapitalAccount...
First, we select the columns from each table, add a new column in each of the data table in the list called `type` and assign the economic variables in the column. Next, we use `rbindlist()` to bind the list now that your data tables have the exact columns.

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(date = rep(seq(from = as.Date('2019-01-01'), to = as.Date('2019-01-05'), by = 'day'), 5),
                  US = runif(25),
                  Argentina = runif(25),
                  Thailand = runif(25),
                  China = runif(25))
df2 <- data.table(date = rep(seq(from = as.Date('2019-01-01'), to = as.Date('2019-01-05'), by = 'day'), 5),
                  US = runif(25),
                  Argentina = runif(25),
                  Japan = runif(25))

l1 <- list(df1, df2)
names(l1) <- c('GDP', 'CPI')

x <- rbindlist(l1, idcol = 'type', fill = TRUE) # this works even when the columns are different for each table
```

Now we have all the data tables combine, we can reshape the table to make look like the result you wanted.

```
x1 <- melt(x, id.vars = c('date', 'type'), measure.vars = c('US', 'Argentina'), variable.name = 'country', value.name = 'value')
dcast(x1, date + country ~ type, value.var = 'value')
```

Comment: It might be a little cleaner to use the `idcol` arg of `rbindlist` to generate the type column. Skip that line in your loop, and use `x <- rbindlist(l1, idcol = "type")` - it will automatically create a column named "type" populated with the names of `l1`.

Comment: Further, you could skip the loop entirely, just `rbindlist` everything. You already specify the columns needed in `melt`, the other columns will be ignored. OP can get whatever countries they want from the full `x`.

Comment: I appreciate the help from yall.